# Strange Compilation Error on Online Judge for Priority Queue

Tags: java, data-structures, compiler-errors, priority-queue

I have a code that runs fine on my IDE as well as Ideone Online Compiler but gives me an error on an Online Jude running the same version of JAVA. I've pasted the link below further ahead.

I have a custom Datatype Called Node which implements a comparator

```
    public static class Node implements Comparator<Node>
    {
        int v1,v2,w,c;

        Node(int v1,int v2,int w,int c)
        {
            this.v1=v1;
            this.v2=v2;
            this.w=w;
            this.c=c;
        }
        @Override
        public int compare(Node o1, Node o2)
        {
            if(o1.c!=o2.c)
            {
                return o2.c-o1.c;
            }
            else
            {
                if(o1.c==1)
                {
                    return (o2.w-o1.w);
                }
                else
                {
                    return (o1.w-o2.w);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in the main method, I instantiate a PriorityQueue as:

```
Queue<Node> pq=new PriorityQueue<Node>(new Node());
```

and add Details corresponding to the parameters of the constructor.
As i mentioned, this runs FINE on my system as well as an online compiler

Here is the link to a successful compiled execution: http://ideone.com/6VKBwP

On CodeChef Online  Judge, i get a **strange Compilation Error as:**

```
Main.java:89: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor PriorityQueue(COALSCAM.Node)
location: class java.util.PriorityQueue<COALSCAM.Node>
            Queue<Node> pq=new PriorityQueue<Node>(new Node());
                           ^
1 error
```

Here is the link to the submission which gives the compilation Error: 
http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/7021134

Here is a link to all my submissions. I have solved the problem by using a TreeSet as a heap instead of the PriorityQueue though i want to resolve this issue
http://www.codechef.com/status/COALSCAM,bholagabbar

Any ideas why this is happening? **Why does it run find on both my system as well as Ideone but fails to compile here?** Honestly, this has never happened before

Comment: I suspect that your versions of Java being used are different.

Comment: The code in the compilation error doesn't match the code you say you use to instantiate the queue (different numbers of arguments). Are you sure that is the code you are using?

Comment: Yeah I tried all variations of instantiation. Sorry ill update them to the same. I already had so many error submissions I must've picked a wrong one

Comment: As for the JAVA versons, both Ideone and CodeChef use JAVA 8.025. I use 8.40 on my system

Comment: Updated the details. Have a look

Comment: Why does it say error in Main.java, at your link there is no Main.java

Comment: No idea. I executed the same code to verify and got the same error. Pick any submission from the link of all the submissions. See for yourself

Comment: This is really weird because CodeChef is powered by SPOJ which is inturn powered by Ideone. If it runs on one it has to run on the other. They even run the same 8_u25 java version